# Annotation issue: @PrepareForTest cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber-junit

I am quite new to Selenium Webdriver with cucumber and is facing an issue while running the Junit test. I tried searching for the resolution to this issue on different forums but didn't get anything helpful, probably since I am new to this.

Below is the code where the problem is. All and any help is appreciated.

```
package firstCucumber;

import org.junit.runner.*;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.*;

import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.*;
import org.junit.Test;


@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@PrepareForTest(TestRunner.class)

@CucumberOptions(
        features = "Feature",
        glue = {"stepDefiition"}
        )


public class TestRunner {

}
```

It says @PrepareForTest cannot be resolved to a type at the line where @ PrepareForTest is written

Answer (score 3):

Add powermock-core-1.6.5.jar to the build path. I faced similar issue and it got resolved once after adding this jar